# Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. SharePoint 2013 JSOM

Tags: custom-list, caml-query, jsom

I am trying to retrieve items from a Sharepoint 2013 list using JSOM with CAML query.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Hai</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
 this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
```

Exactly at After clientContext.load I am getting an exception like below:

> Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: clientObject
>       at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd?d=z-TpJGMxry662OihfqljDL26fiN46CFgw-dc63w_0oeRlpp6N9gJsaBwPeMFyqrxHJ8pqpl9ZXTIDm…:237)
>       at Function.Error$argumentNull [as argumentNull] (ScriptResource.axd?d=z-TpJGMxry662OihfqljDL26fiN46CFgw-dc63w_0oeRlpp6N9gJsaBwPeMFyqrxHJ8pqpl9ZXTIDm…:279)
>       at SP_ClientContext.SP_ClientRuntimeContext$load [as load] (VM2726 sp.runtime.debug.js?rev=VFkBZgkYpbAZS6abSrBqIg%3D%3D:3261)
>       at Publish (AllNewsFeed.aspx:1113)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (XYZ.aspx:2109)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have used the MSDN sample.

Try it as below:

```
var listItemCollection = null;   

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', queryListItems);

function queryListItems() {  
     var context = new SP.ClientContext();        
     var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CustomList'); //change as per your list name        
     var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();        
     caml.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Hai</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
     listItemCollection = list.getItems(caml);  
     context.load(listItemCollection);        
     context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
}  


function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {  
     var enumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();  
     while (enumerator.moveNext()) 
     {  
        var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  
        console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));         
     }      
}  

function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {  
    console.log('Message: ' + args.get_message());        
}
```